# Inset faces - overlapping issue

Tags: mesh

I have multiple "cells", I would like to inset each of the cells by a factor of 0.1:
[image]

So far so good, but when I try to inset the cells by a larger factor, they start to overlap:

[image]

Is it possible to tell Blender to "drop" the extra vertices which are breaking the model? It seems like each inset requires less vertices to form the smaller cell. Otherwise if I have to do model with more "cells" and multiple insets per cell, I have to do a lot of manual fixes to just fix one cell.

Is there a better way to do this? Thanks!

Comment: I downloaded an add-on for inset features but I don't remember the name of it right now (EDIT: I think it is Mesh Tools, install it via Preferences). If you don't need to be super-precise and if it won't haunt your dreams (:P), just change pivot mode to Median, extrude-cancel the region, and scale the n-gon inward by a factor of 0.9

Comment: @hatinacat2000 thanks for the reply! Can you please tell me how can I do this step: "and scale the n-gon inward by a factor of 0.9", thanks!

Comment: You know how when you extrude something you can right-click to leave the extruded faces where you extruded them from (provide no transformation on the extruded faces)? As long as you keep those faces selected, you can tap the "S" key and "0.9" to scale those face to 0.9

Answer (score 3):

With the built in tools, it is not possible to avoid overlapping in such cases when applying `Inset Faces`, but you can clean up the mesh afterwards:

1. Use `Inset Faces` with the shortcut <kbd>I</kbd>
2. Select the two edges that overlap
3. Move the cursor to the point of intersection: <kbd>Space</kbd> -> *Snap To* -> *Cursor to Edge Intersection*
4. Mark the points that intersect: <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>LMB</kbd>
5. Join the selected points at the position of the cursor: <kbd>M</kbd> -> *At Cursor*

[image]