# Thicken walls in geometry nodes properly, accounting for concave corners

Tags: geometry-nodes, geometry, extrude

I have run into situations where I wanted to do this multiple times now, but I have yet to find a way to do it.

Lets say I have the following geometry, generated using geometry nodes:

[image: slightly extruded walls]

And I want to thicken this wall by the amount I need, I would end up with the following result:

[image: further extruded walls]

As you can see from the Z-fighting, the resulting geometry isn't great (even though the outside shape is what I want).

I get that this is a fairly non-trivial problem to solve. The only thing I can think of is somehow fixing the geometry after doing the wall extrusion. But I don't think there is any way to do that in geometry nodes. I guess some kind of remesh operation would be a sort of solution. But there is no way I'd end up with acceptable geometry for my purposes like that.

Therefore, I was wondering if someone here knows of a way to make walls thicker in geometry nodes without this problem?

[image]

Comment: The topic is tricky, but maybe this answer will help you: https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/245856/145249

Comment: @quellenform After trying to decipher that question's solution (not quite having figured out the geometry proximity) I found a similar way to detect the intersecting points. But just deleting those isn't gonna work here, because I am not working with a curve. So just deleting points is gonna make holes in geometry geometry. Also, that method only works with a lot of subdivisions  (or a resample curve in their case). Ideally I'd somehow be able to figure out the crossing point of 2 lines. And just set position to that, and then merge distance. Then I could mostly keep the original geometry.

Comment: That's correct, of course: my approach would require that you build this geometry from scratch, based on curves. Unfortunately, I don't know of any other way that relies exclusively on *Geometry Nodes*.

Comment: If a destructive workflow without *Geometry Nodes* is an option for you, you could also use the following technique:: https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/262940/145249

Comment: Sadly, a non geometry nodes solution wouldn't really help me much.

Comment: OK, then it would be helpful if you share your blend file with us, or at least clearly show how you constructed this in *Geometry Nodes* to avoid misunderstandings.

Comment: I found this other solution: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/265909/how-can-i-scale-a-2d-shape-with-constant-thickness-inwards (solution 1). Which I think does almost what I want, and I might be able to mold into what I am trying to do here (even though I don't really understand it). I'll try that tomorrow, rn it is time for me to go to bed.

Also, I attached my blender file to the question

Comment: After a lot of work trying to create nodes that reliably do this, and failing. I think I am gonna wait for this node, which sounds like it'd be perfect to abuse for this: https://conference.blender.org/2022/presentations/1351/